# How can I improve the speed of this code with proper async/await/promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, promise, async-await

Using Node.js, I have got a task to improve the code I have created. This code do 60 HTTP requests and uses libraries for that.

It takes 30 seconds to do all HTTP requests and save each to a file!

It is said that is possible to do those requests in 3 seconds with:

**1. Proper management of async promises**

**2. A bit smarter caching**

**3. Not using cluster**

**4. Only add the overhead once**

I am afraid that I am not sure where to start understand what I can do exactly.

So below code gets an array of 60 items where each one is one HTTP request:

```js
const exchanges = ccxt.exchanges
```

Those goes into the: worker = async function and at the end of code: await Promise.all(workers) wait for them to finish.

**I am not sure where to begin to actually be able to come down to 3 seconds. How can it be possible to improve the speed of this code?**

```js
'use strict';

const ccxt  = require ('ccxt')
    , log   = require ('ololog').noLocate // npm install ololog
    , fs    = require ('fs')

    // the numWorkers constant defines the number of concurrent workers
    // those aren't really threads in terms of the async environment
    // set this to the number of cores in your CPU * 2
    // or play with this number to find a setting that works best for you
    , numWorkers = 8

;(async () => {

    // make an array of all exchanges
    const exchanges = ccxt.exchanges

        .filter (id => ![ 'cap1', 'cap2' ].includes (id))

        // instantiate each exchange and save it to the exchanges list
        .map (id => new ccxt[id] ({
            'enableRateLimit': true,
        }))

    // the worker function for each "async thread"
    const worker = async function () {

        // while the array of all exchanges is not empty
        while (exchanges.length > 0) {

            // pop one exchange from the array
            const exchange = exchanges.pop()

            // check if it has the necessary method implemented
            if (exchange.has['fetchTickers']) {

                // try to do "the work" and handle errors if any
                try {

                    // fetch the response for all tickers from the exchange
                    const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers()

                    // make a filename from exchange id
                    const filename = '/myproject/tickers/' + exchange.id + 'Tickers.json'

                    // save the response to a file
                    fs.writeFileSync(filename, JSON.stringify({ tickers }));

                } catch (e) { } //Error
            }
        }
    }

    // create numWorkers "threads" (they aren't really threads)
    const workers = [ ... Array (numWorkers) ].map (_ => worker ())

    // wait for all of them to execute or fail
    await Promise.all (workers)

}) ()
```

Comment: Who said it is possible? I mean if you are going to do it in a synchronous manner than you are waiting for each call to complete before you do the next. Seems like you would want to not do it synchronously.

Comment: Reduce the number of requests you're doing.  Example, find a way to combine all the "fetchTickers" from the "exchanges" into one request.

Comment: btw why are you using `writeFileSync` if performance matters? While a synchronous operation is running the node Event Loop is blocked.

Comment: @James I beleive it is not possible in the library to combine all the "fetchTickers" into one request since it is completely different URLS

Comment: @ Alberti Buonarroti Yes perheps this one thing I can improve. I wonder if it is possible to run those requests in somekind of even more "parallel" approach than it is coded now? The hints I have got is using async/await/promises in a more wise way.

Comment: So look at how to run multiple promises at once and maintain the order

Comment: You might want to check [How do you make axios GET request wait?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54684628/5639677). Using `await` inside a loop means that the execution does not proceed until the promise is resolved. This slows down your code. You should push your requests in an array and use `Promsie.all` to wait until all promises are resolved.

Comment: Consider doing a benchmark, it's unknown what takes the most time. `sync` smells, you could address it before asking, there's already `fs.promises`. You likely don't need to be restricted to 8 workers because you don't depend on CPU cores. In case requests can be fired simultaneously, you may not need workers at all. It's unknown what needs to be cached, likely specific to your case (ccxt).

Comment: @Alberti Buonarroti that was interesting. Thanks for the link and info. I will look into the link you did send. This could be something that is a bottleneck.

Comment: @estus This is an interesting test to do. I will check on this also. Yes, this (ccxt) seems to take quite long time to be initialized when start running the code. Perheps a few seconds. Is this possible to overcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making things more complicated than they need to be. You can do all of the work within the `map` callback, then use `Promise.all(promises)` to wait for all of the operations to complete. This process does take longer than the expected "3 seconds" (15 seconds in my case) and there are a lot of errors produced (like missing apiToken, or fetchTickers not being implemented), but this could be an issue with my environment (I've never used `ccxt` before and I don't have any apiTokens).

This is the implementation I came up with, hopefully it helps you meet your needs:

```
const ccxt = require('ccxt');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

(async () => {
    const start = Date.now();

    const dumps = ccxt.exchanges
        .filter((id) => !['coinmarketcap', 'theocean'].includes(id))
        .map(async (id) => {
            const Exchange = ccxt[id];
            const exchange = new Exchange({enableRateLimit: true});
            if (exchange.has['fetchTickers']) {
                try {
                    const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers();
                    const dumpFile = path.join(__dirname, 'exchanges', `${id}-Tickers.json`);
                    await fs.promises.writeFile(dumpFile, JSON.stringify(tickers));
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                }
            }
        });

    await Promise.all(dumps);

    const end = Date.now();
    console.log(`Done in ${(end - start) / 1000} seconds`);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! The code is interesting, but the .json files are empty though? They only contain this string: "[object Object]" Perheps it is close and something is missing that I have not figured out yet?

Comment: Right, you need to convert the object to a string before writing to a file. I made an edit to the answer.

Comment: Yes I was just to post that too. I found it out also :) Thank you for this code. It took 15 seconds here also to download that is a great improvment. I will try out and see if it would be possible to split up the exchanges into different dumps/ async calls to make them parallel somehow and make it even faster :) Thank you!

Comment: The requests and file writes are already running in parallel, I'm not sure how much further this could be improved performance wise.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am not sure either. The 'guru' of the library unfortunately have some approach to do it in 3 seconds but wont tell and instead let me try to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

I try to see if it would be possible to do it even faster. I try to cache up all possible memories needed.. Before actually doing the .fetchTickers() request.

I managed to go down even to 9 seconds from 15 seconds as it seemed. But this code below is even one step further but I do receive compile errors and are not sure what I am doing wrong.

Error is:

**ReferenceError: id is not defined**

Isn't id passed along in the 'exchange' object that is .pushed into 'exchangesArray'?

I am trying to put the exchange object into an array first with all the time that takes:

```js
var exchangesArray = [];
```

Then with this "exchangesArray" in place, I try to execute the function that does the fetchTickers:

```js
'use strict';
const ccxt = require('ccxt');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

//Cache some memories first
var exchangesArray = [];
(async () => {
  const allexchanges = ccxt.exchanges.filter((id) => !['coinmarketcap', 'theocean'].includes(id))
        .map(async (id) => {
            const Exchange = ccxt[id];
            const exchange = new Exchange({ enableRateLimit: true });
            if (exchange.has['fetchTickers']) {

                exchangesArray.push(exchange);
            }
        });

    await Promise.all(allexchanges);
})();

//Use cached memories to do the "fetchTickers()" as fast as possible
(async () => {
    const start = Date.now();

    const exchanges = exchangesArray;
    while (exchanges.length > 0) {

        // pop one exchange from the array
        const exchange = exchanges.pop()

        try {
            const tickers = await exchange.fetchTickers();
            const dumpFile = path.join(__dirname, 'exchanges', `${id}-Tickers.json`);
            await fs.promises.writeFile(dumpFile, JSON.stringify(tickers));
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }

    }

    await Promise.all(exchanges);

    const end = Date.now();
    console.log(`Done in ${(end - start) / 1000} seconds`);
})();
```

Comment: I struggle with the: exchangesArray.push(exchange); It seems that the 'exchange' object doesn't have all information when .pushed into the 'exchangesArray'?